# (VB.NET Word.Application) Reading text from cursor didn't work correctly

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a sub that msgbox the word from the current cursor to the previous seperator (or punctuation, control) in a word document. Here's what I have written in that function.

> ```
>     Dim mStart = mwrdApp.Selection.Range.Start - 1 ' mwrdApp is current word application in my program
>     Dim mEnd = mStart
>     Dim mText = mwrdDoc.Range.Text ' mwrdDoc is current document opened in mwrdApp
>     Dim mWord = ""
>     Do
>         If mStart = -1 Then Exit Do
>         If Char.IsSeparator(mText(mStart)) Or Char.IsPunctuation(mText(mStart)) Or Char.IsControl(mText(mStart)) Then Exit Do
>         mWord = mText(mStart) + mWord
>         mStart -= 1
>     Loop
>     MsgBox(mWord)
> ```

[Here's the image of the document that I'm testing, with the position of the cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko1zg.png)

However, the msgbox shown "Test" instead of "TestingStrin".

I don't know why this happened. Can anyone explain this to me? And is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

PS:
It turned out that the value of `mStart` is `75` and the length of `mText` is `86`, which is weird (`mStart` should equal to length of `mText` minus `1`)
Also, [here's the value of mText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bp72.png). Is the "weird character" is the format of table?

Comment: What is the value of `mText` on line 3 ? You should probably put `Debug.Print` statements to see what is the value of your variables and at which point it is terminating. It hard to guess with this much info.

Comment: @NeverHopeless:I've added the value of mStart, mText and length of mText

Comment: Clearly your algorithm is wrong (-> this is the first and only thought which should come to your mind when you get a result different than what you expect). If you want to get help quickly (and/or at all) reduce the irrelevant bits and post a clear and simple sample input which anyone might use intuitively. Once you have confirmed that your algorithm (loop) is right, you might start doubting about how the Interop Word ranges + the position of the cursor are defined. This is a (multi-step) debugging problem (provoked by a wrong approach) which you shouldn't expect others to do for you.